# Page.Request in OnLoad of a Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the OnLoad of a server control I would like to do the following:

```
string username = Page.Request["UsernameTextBox"];
```

The actual controls are then created in CreateChildControls (so I will only need to do this on a postback).

The problem is that I cannot use the IDs in this way, because the control in this case must be referenced by name.If I hard code it i can solve the problem by doing this:

```
string username = Page.Request["ctl02$ctl00$ctl02$ctl00$ctl02$ctl03$ctl03$ctl02$ctl01"];
```

Of course this would be a bad solution considering that the control hierarchy could change. So my question is this: Is there a way for me to get this control name in OnLoad. If I could find the method that calculates the name from the NamingContainer or something i would be fine.

(Let's not discuss this wierd design in this login control/page - consider it as the constant of my question).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ClientIDMode property of your username textbox to static.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx